# Run a CodeIgniter project issue

Tags: codeigniter, wamp

I am new to CodeIgniter, I have a project named **task_board**.
everything is OK. However when I typed **localhost/task_board** in browser, the following page is opened:
 [image]

When I clicked on the highlighted project, following page is opened:
[image]

localhost without project is looked like:
[image]

Comment: Did you remove the index.php from URL by editing .htaccess file ?

Comment: Yes, there was a little error in .htaccess

Comment: so please mark the comment as useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable rewrite module - please follow these steps

1) Open apache’s configuration file using - {wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf

2) Search for the following string:

## LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

and uncomment it (remove the ‘#’ sign).

3) Now search for another string AllowOverride None and replace it by AllowOverride All
This will be on two places, so you will need to replace two times
Finally save the changes,

close your text editor and restart your apache server.
That’s all.

Please follow these steps and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I did as you told, but still above issue is exist.

Comment: @AyazKhan Good Job...can you please mark a upvote  ? if you think my answer was helpful to you

Comment: The basic reason I found behind the above issue was "I did not mention index route correctly in .htaccess"